# JS file not being served over HTTPS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mod-rewrite, socket.io, mod-proxy

I have turned on HTTPS on a website, and I have discovered that a JS file that until now was being served correctly when requested from a script tag in my template is now failing all the time.

The request that works is something like:

`http://dev.mysite.com:54346/socket.io/socket.io.js`

And the one that doesn't is not that much different:

`https://dev.mysite.com:54346/socket.io/socket.io.js`

Looking at the output of `lsof -i :5346` and `top` and stopping the script I've been able to figure out that a node script that we start with `forever` is actually somehow answering the petition that works, but not the other one. I don't know too much about node, but looking into the code of that script and its requirements (`socket.io`) I haven't seen anything that makes me think it could work only with HTTP and not with HTTPS.

I don't actually understand how does this work, because I haven't seen any configuration of Apache that could even remotely mean something like "redirect this requests to this process".

The only solution I could think of was to redirect the petition trough HTTPS to HTTP, but I tried using `mod_proxy` and `mod_rewrite` without any luck at all.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm gonna mark this as resolved because we are pretty sure now it is more a nodejs issue than an Apache conf one. Thanks anyway, Ed Williams!

Comment: No worries! It turned out that I just needed to set up an HTTPS server with node.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like a port issue.  If the server is configured to use port 54346 for http, you'd have another port set for https.  Have you used Fiddler or another tool to see what port your secure server is on?  I typically use 80 for http, 443 for https.

See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/bind.html for information on binding ports for your Apache server.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at Fiddler later.
Where can I check the port used other than in the vhosts .conf files?
There the server is configured to listen to the port 80 for HTTP and 443 for HTTPS; I have no idea where Apache is configured to do something with port 54346.

Comment: Updated the answer with a link to the Apache page for configuring your ports.  I'm a Microsoft guy and haven't used Apache in 20 years, but that page appeared to have what you'd need.

Comment: Thank you for the link, but there is not any ```Listen``` directive in use in my virtual hosts, at least in the files in ```sites-available``` directory; the config for these virtual hosts specify ports 80 for the HTTP one and 443 for the HTTPS one, so everything seems correct.
I'm gonna try to check port redirecting or forwarding config, because I don't know what else to look at.